# Creating a KML file from a XML file

Tags: python, xml, kml, google-earth

How can I create KML files from the XML files using python.
I have a lot of XML files. I have already parsed the data from the XML files using the SAX parser.

Now I want to create KML files from the data that I have parsed.

Is there any other way apart from `xml.dom.minidom` to write the KML file.
I am currently thinking of creating a template KML file. Then copying the template KML file and filling the 'data' in it.

Can anybody suggest a better way ?

My main concern is Maintainability (writing the data using minidom is pretty confusing for somebody to read).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [xml.etree.ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).  Here's a short example creating a couple of points in a KML file:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

class Kml(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = et.Element('kml')
        self.doc = et.SubElement(self.root,'Document')

    def add_placemark(self,name,desc,lat,long,alt):
        pm = et.SubElement(self.doc,'Placemark')
        et.SubElement(pm,'name').text = name
        et.SubElement(pm,'description').text = desc
        pt = et.SubElement(pm,'Point')
        et.SubElement(pt,'coordinates').text = '{},{},{}'.format(lat,long,alt)

    def write(self,filename):
        tree = et.ElementTree(self.root)
        tree.write(filename)

kml = Kml()
kml.add_placemark('Location1','Description1',-120,45,0)
kml.add_placemark('Location2','Description2',60,-45,0)
kml.write('out.kml')
```

Comment: I think I'll go with minidom (if given a choice between minidom and ElementTree). If there is any other thing out there, do let me know. But your code has given me the idea of class. Thanks for that. Make the Kml class deal with all the complexity of the KML and just call the clean interfaces of it.

Comment: "long" should come before "lat" in the .format, I believe. Thanks for the code tho!